# regular expression Text in quotation marks

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a  built-in wildcard search (Ms-word) that collects the text between quotation mark, BUT the beginning of the quotation mark should not start with X letter (before the quotation) and the end should not end with X letter (before the quotation).
for example:

> **X'dfgdfgd 'abcd 'X fgt'1234'5**

should return the string:

> **abcd 'X fgt**
>   i.e this first shortest string that matches the criteria

I have the following reg expression

> "[‘'][!^13^l^t]@['’]"

and

> "(\'*?\')"

but from here I could not succeed in progress to my goal.

Thank you in advance!
Asi

Comment: Do you really mean a regular expression (RegEx) or do you mean Word's built-in wildcard search? The two are *not* the same and usually it makes no sense to use RegEx in Word since it can only be applied to strings and not Word's document content.

Comment: you right! I need it to Word's built-in wildcard search

Comment: You can use the [edit] link below a question to add or correct information in the question, itself. Information in comments tends to get overlooked...

Comment: @macropod I did invest without success

Comment: So show us what you *tried*. It's a trivial change to the code I posted in the other thread...

Answer (score 0):

Try this regExp

```
[^X]('[\w\s']*')
```

[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/Vl1poF/1)

Comment: almost... for example in the following string sample: X'dfgdfgd 'abcd 'X fgt'asdsw'   the result should be 'abcd 'X fgt' and not ''abcd 'X fgt'asdsw''

Comment: BTW: another problem is that I need it to work in VB macro and not  RegEx (sorry if i mislead in advance)